# How to set vertical align of elements that exist into a div tag to center with css?

Tags: html, css

I try to to set vertical align of elements that exist into a div tag to center.
Please advice

```
<div class="new_div">
     <h3>نام من</h3>
    <p>توضیحات من</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
</div>
```

css

```
.new_div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you  change your html structure?

Comment: If you want to add a div :OK

Comment: In this case the elements appear like this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvlfA.gif. Spaces most be deleted

Comment: If the container DIV has no height, it is tall exactly as required to contain the elements inside, so you don't need to vertically center anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell;`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spn4c1aj/)

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.new_div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="new_div">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>نام من</h3>
    <p>توضیحات من</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Additional space appeared

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/spn4c1aj/2/)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

For vertical center? Try something along the lines of

```
.new_div {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px; /* Same as new_div height */
 }
```

Comment: You can not add height to div

Comment: Why can't you add a height to the div?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Get them aligned next to one another, vertically aligned in the whole page or what?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to

- use the `display` attribute
- in combination with the `vertical-align` attribute

---

```html
    <div style="display: table; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
          <div>
            <h3>نام من</h3>
            <p>توضیحات من </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">بیشتر ...</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```